# asp.net - OutputCache for page which contains shopping cart?

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page where in one ContentPlaceHolder I put my shopping cart:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="continutMeniuContulMeu" runat="server">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelCos" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <user:ShoppingCart ID="shoppingCartControl" runat="server" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I now have a page where I display all the products, page which uses the master page from above and which is cached for one hour:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="*" VaryByControl="shoppingCartControl" %>
```

You see that I want, when the shoppingCart content is changed and the user revisits that page, to reflect this shopping cart update, so I put VaryByControl.

But it seems it still serves the old cached page...

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

varyByControl works based on the value for the specified control.   Try doing http sniffing (using something like fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and compare the value being sent to the server for your control.

In your case look for the value of "shoppingCartControl" in the HTTP Request and see if the value being sent to the server is truly different between your two scenarios.